# How to know that all firebase data messages are received?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send data messages to my Android app. It is possible that the devices goes offline and that there are multiple data messages queued on the server to be send to a specific device.

When a message is received I have to execute some specific code based on the data inside the message.

Is there some way to be sure that when you receive a message in onMessageReceived() that there are no other messages in the queue to be delivered to my device?

I am asking this because when receiving multiple messages, the data in all messages need to be combined before starting my processing.

Thanks!

Comment: Would a [collapsible message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages) work for your use-case?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I've looked into this, but it is not sufficient enough for me. How we envisioned to use the message is to include the tables that need to be synced. When there are multiple messages pending I want to combine them to know all the tables I have to sync and only perform 1 sync. When I'm using collapsible messages, the server will overwrite the previous message that was not send. But maybe the two messages will contain a different set of tables. Then I should have a way to combine them at the server end?

Comment: I was thinking about building in a delay after receiving a push message. During that delay other notifications can come in and hopefully all will be received before I then start my sync. Only not sure whether this is working under all circumstances...

Answer (score 0):

I think using FCM *alone* isn't the best for this use case. In general, FCM's expected behavior is to send the message(s) as soon as feasible.

One thing to remind also is that FCM is a push notification service. So a use-case where you need data to be synced is *not a good match*.

The way I can think of that you can use FCM here is to simply send a push notification, informing the user that there needs data to be synced. Upon tapping the notification, you can use a [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) (not really sure what data you need synced, but for downloads, it usually this) to download the data you need, then process the data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reaction. We don't want to show the notification to our users. We want the app to handle the notification autonomously. The notification is only for letting the app know that there is new data for him and that the device can then request the data from the server. But since we have an application with lots of data and tables, we want to let the device know in the notifications what data is changed for him, so that he does not have to sync all tables. The issue here is, when there are multiple notifications in queue, I want to combine them all and perform one sync.